# location.path() not redirecting to page

Tags: angularjs

In node this is how I define my details route (render as jade and send).

```
app.get('/details', function(req, res){

        jade.renderFile('details.jade', function(err, html){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              }
              res.send(html);
          });

      });
```

In jade with 'blah' is clicked then calls navigateToPath function with params.

```
 a(ng-click="navigateToPath(date_obj_key, part)") blah
```

In angular, this function should go to this path. The url path changes in the browser but it does not REDIRECT to the page. Help (yes I am injecting the location service)

```
  $scope.navigateToPath = function(date, part){
  var path = '/details?date='+date+'&part_type='+part;
  $location.path('/details').replace();   //also tried $location.url(path)
  $scope.apply();   //also tried $scope.$apply and $rootScope.$apply as func
  console.log($location.path());
}
```

Comment: You sure your "/details" is being recognized as Client Route.js ?   $location.path('/details') - should work just like that

Comment: I'm using node.js for the routing. yes when I do go to that route it works manually but it does not work on the click event

Comment: Try $window.location = path and make sure you inject $window.

Comment: Thank you Costas. That ended up working!

Comment: if it helped could you up vote my comment?

Comment: sorry don't have enough rep to do that. If you post an answer then I can mark it correct

Comment: @Shapiro: Wasn't mine correct?

Comment: @malix Do you need to put the origin? I am just curious, I was able to successfully call a rest service by just assigning a path which was appended to the end of the url.

Comment: @Costas For me made it into a ful URL, but at -2, I have deleted it! People downvote without comments... very unstackoverflowish :)

Comment: @malix yeah that is annoying. could be that they tried exactly what you put and it didn't work for them on the first try and they didn't play around with it, try different things to make it work. set break points to see values of certain variables in order to get what they want.

Comment: @shapiro if this helped/worked for you could you accept an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Fire Fox developer tools(F12) and put a break point on where I used $window.location in my project and looked at the values in $window.location and this what it shows:

[image]

It seems like this would work. for both a location in the same folder or sub-folder as well as going to a completely different web site.

```
 $window.location = $window.location.origin + path
```

or

```
 $window.location = <whatever website you want to go to>
```

In my case I was just using the $window.location to call a rest service to download a file that the user selected from a ui-grid while still staying on the same page. and this may have worked for me because my scenario is a bit different then what yours is I think. so all I had to do was

```
 $window.location = "../../services" + "<path to my rest service>" + $scope.shortCode + "/" + $scope.wireInstSelectedRow.entity.fileName;
```

@shapiro I am not sure why this does not work

```
 $location.path('/details').replace();
```

I tried the same thing originally in my project and based on the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location It seems like that would work and what its supposed to be used for but what I noticed is it would put a '#' character in the url before it put the path I wanted it to take which was preventing it from going to that page.  Anyhow for me it seems like as long as you are going to an html page that is in the same folder or sub-folder just doing

```
 $window.location = <the path you want to go to>;
```

is a good solution... at least it did the trick for me.  Hope this helps.